# How to return a List<> from a WCF call

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf, list, serialization

I'm just getting up to speed using WCF. I've created my WCF service and I'm hosting it in a console app.

My custom class is shared between the service and the client.

```
[Serializable]
public class clsPlinker
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Game : Object
    {
        public Game(string name, string desc, int GameNum)
        {
            _Name = name;
            _Desc = desc;
            _GameNum = GameNum;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my interface

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IPlinkerWCFservice
{
    [OperationContract]
    List<clsPlinker.Game> GetGameList();
}
```

Here is my service

```
public class PlinkerWCFservice : IPlinkerWCFservice
{
    public List<clsPlinker.Game> GetGameList()
    {
        List<clsPlinker.Game> lstGames = new List<clsPlinker.Game>();
        // do stuff to load the lstGames
        return lstGames;
    }
}
```

In my Windows Client app, I call the service reference

```
PlinkerWCFservice.PlinkerWCFserviceClient wcfTest = new PlinkerWCFservice.PlinkerWCFserviceClient("NetTcpBinding_IPlinkerWCFservice");
List<clsPlinker.Game> lstGames = wcfTest.GetGameList().ToList();
```

The code won't compile giving me the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   `System.Collections.Generic.List<TabletController.PlinkerWCFservice.clsPlinkerGame>` 
>   to `System.Collections.Generic.List<PlinkerCommon.clsPlinker.Game>`

TabletController is the namespace of my WinForms app.

In another method, I can return a single clsPlinker.Game, but trying to return a List has me stumped. I've searched for hours, to no avail. What am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change like this,

Your result is of type `TabletController.PlinkerWCFservice.clsPlinkerGame` but you are having `clsPlinker.Game`

```
List<TabletController.PlinkerWCFservice.clsPlinkerGame> lstGames = wcfTest.GetGameList().ToList();
```

Comment: That solved the compile error, thanks! Now how can I type cast it back into a clsPlinker.game object? Since both the client and the server reference the same class, shouldn't I be able to do this?

I get the same error if I try casting them as clsPlinker.Game objects while iterating over the list.

Comment: I ended up not sharing the class between the projects. After retrieving the results, I just assign the values to a new clsPlinker.Game object.

Answer (score 1):

When adding service reference, change collection type from System.Array to System.Collections.Generic.List and Reuse types in all referenced assemblies.

Comment: Changing the collection type doesn't change anything. If I check the Reuse Types checkbox, all the methods in my service reference disappear.